# Power a large solenoid from a microcontroller?

Tags: mosfet, solenoid

I am trying to control a large solenoid, rated at 10 Amps and 12 Volts.  I am trying to use [this](http://datasheet.octopart.com/2SK3568-Toshiba-datasheet-107811.pdf) mosfet, however I keep burning them out.  I have a rectifier diode connected across the solenoid, and I am powering the whole circuit from only 7 volts.  How do I prevent the mosfets from burning out?  My circuit is like the one below.  The diode is a 1N4007.  I have a heatsink on my mosfet.

[image]

Comment: Please convert that to an actual schematic.

Comment: Pretty cartoon. What mosfet are you using? What gate voltage is it getting?

Comment: I am using an 2SK3568, at 7 volts, with a gate voltage of 5 volts.

Comment: Totally unsuitable choice of mosfet.

Comment: This is could go really wrong.

Comment: Would a RFP30N06LE work better?

Comment: First, of all its gonna heat up, use a large heatsink, also try adding some capacitance across solenoid to ground in case it may break the limit of drain to source breakdown voltage before you can even trigger the gate. If this even doesn't work try to ground some current using resistance from the solenoid to ground or may be use resistance to limit current in main circuit??.

Comment: -1 for the cartoon instead of a schematic.

Comment: +1 for going through the effort of visualizing ones system as good as personally possible, and having a good explanation to go with it. Still, a schematic would have been more concise, I agree.

Comment: @Marcus: We don't tolerate wiring diagrams, no matter how pretty, as substitutes for schematics to describe circuits.  When people come to our house, they need to follow our rules.  This isn't a site for where any hobbyist can be fast and loose with terms and wishy washy with the details.  Learn how it's done, or don't come here.  Schematics are how its done.  By giving the OP a pass, you send all the wrong information.

Comment: @olin I didn't know that. Would you mind pointing me to the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solenoid resistance is 1.2 ohms (12/10). Now here's the MOSFET: -

[image]

I've highlighted in red what the problem is.....

With a gate voltage of 5 volts and a load current of 5.8 amps (7/1.2), the volt drop of the MOSFET is going to be about 2.6 volts. Therefore it will dissipate 5.8 x 2.6 watts = 15 watts - how big is your heat sink!!

Comment: What would be a good mosfet to use?

Comment: Would a RFP30N06LE be suitable?

Comment: Just take a look for something that is "logic level" driven and has an on resistance in the low tens of milliohms then double check the data sheet and look for the graph above.

Answer (score 2):

Your MOSFET has a low on resistance, but only when its gate voltage is sufficiently high:

[image]

With the much lower voltage you use to drive the MOSFET (5V) your will only turn it partially on, so some significant current will flow, but most of the 60V voltage will be dropped by the MOSFET, hence it will be killed.

You must find a way to drive the gate with 0-12V. One way it to use a separate 12V supply and a MOSFET gate driver chip. Google will help you find plenty of those. Or use a transistor buffer (but that will make the switching slower, with more risk of still burning your MOSFET).

PS what current does that solenoid draw?

Comment: It draws around 5 amps.  Where are the 70 volts from?

Comment: sorry, 60. corrected.

Comment: With an Rds of 0.5 Ohm and 5A the mosfet will still dissipate 12.5W (even when driven correctly), so it needs a nice big heatsink.

Comment: I'm not actually using 60 volts, I am only using 7 volts, the picture is from the guide I was following.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen the image you'd want to is the V_DS over V_GS curve on p. 3, middle right. At 5V Gate-source voltage, the voltage drop from drain to source is higher than representable in the chart!

Comment: @Marcus that might be the case for post-mortem analysis, but for design I prefer the table I quoted.

Comment: If you are using 7V to power the solenoid and mosfet, you should choose a mosfet type that has a lower required gate voltage. The one you mentioned is rated for quite high voltages, which in most cases means that it also requires a substantial gate voltage. For lower power voltages there are gazillions of mosfets to choose from that will work with only 5V gate voltage.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen true, this is primarily useful for post-mortem, yet that table says "V_th = 4.0V", and OP is driving the Gate with nearly 5V (I think that's the output high of an arduino), so that we both know that in that state, especially with a large I_DS, you're very much in linear range, but you should explain why, imho.